# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 18140: invalid start byte

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to download stock data from google finance using python3 (please see code below).
I am getting an encoding error (please see below).
Since I have been using python only since a week, I would appreciate some help in debugging this. I have read similar posts regarding this error but unfortunately I could not use the answers (different codes/libraries used/scenarios ...)

[Error]

```
>>> stock_prices = DataReader(ticker, data_source, start, end)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 
137, in DataReader
session=session).read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 
181, in read
params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 
79, in _read_one_data
out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 
98, in _read_url_as_StringIO
out.write(bytes_to_str(text))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 
74, in bytes_to_str
return b.decode(encoding or 'utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 18176: 
invalid start byte
```

[code]:

```
from pandas_datareader import DataReader
from datetime import date
start = date(2016,1,1)
end = date(2016,12,31)
ticker = 'AAPL'
data_source = 'google'
stock_prices = DataReader(ticker, data_source, start, end)
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.3 on Mac OS X Version 10.9.5

Comment: `out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)` need detect which encoding are used, can't convert `ISO` to `utf-8` without encoding.

Comment: Hi dsgdfg, thanks for your response. I am not understanding your answer. Would you please give more details. Thanks